# Function to convert PHP date format to Javascript date format (not the date itself !)

Tags: javascript, php, sql, date, momentjs

I am looking for easy way to convert PHP date format (i.e. Y-m-d H:i:s) to javascript date format (respectively YYYY-mm-dd HH:mm:ss).

**I don't want to convert the date** (there are already answers for this question), I am looking for tool/function to **convert the format code (which I don't know yet, as it is defined by the user in application).**

User can define it in different ways defined by PHP date() i.e. 'Y/m/d H:i' or 'Y-d-m H-i' and I need to use the same format when displaying date in javascript.

Are you aware of any ready convert function to make it?

```
<?php
$timeformat_php = "H:i:s"; //just defined by the user
$time_universal = date( $timeformat_php, strtotime( $time_php ) );
echo date($timeformat_php, $time_universal); //print as defined by user
?>

<script>
var timeformatPhp = '<?php echo $timeformat_php ?>';
var timeformatJavascript = functionThatIamLookingFor (timeformatPhp);
alert(moment($time_universal).format(timeformatJavascript); //printed again the way user defined
</script>
```

Any help will appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I fear that your question is off-topic, see [help/on-topic]. Have a look at [moment-strftime](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/plugins/strftime/) even if I'm not sure it could help you.

Comment: What you're asking for is an ECMAScript formatter that uses the same tokens as PHP. They likely exist, but such questions are off topic here.

Comment: E.g. you can look at the source for [*Fecha.js*](https://github.com/taylorhakes/fecha/blob/master/lib/fecha.umd.js) and starting at line 66 you can see the parse and formatting tokens. So you just need to map the formatting tokens from PHP to Fecha.js and then use the Fecha.js formatter. The same approach can be used with other libraries too. I suggest Fech.js for this as it's less than 300 lines of code and does an excellent job of parsing and formatting.

Comment: My counter is: Don't let the user write their own date format strings at all, because trying to automate the conversion is going to be a nightmare when the user tries to use some esoteric format specifier that doesn't translate. Provide a selection of options they can select from, and if they don't like it they can make a suggestion and/or pound sand.

Comment: Sammitch - Thanks. Very useful counter. I will take under serious consideration!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you're asking is to use PHP formatting tokens to format an ECMAScript Date object, then something like the following might help. It supports all tokens except those for timezone names. I don't think you can do that reliably just with javascript in a browser, though something like node.js may be able to.

There are a few functions to go, such as whether daylight saving is being observed or not and generating an RFC 2822 format string, but they're easy to add I think. It supports quoted characters so you can build strings like:

```
P.format(date, 'jS \\o\\f F, Y') // 1st of August, 2019
```

Any character that doesn't match a token is copied to the output string (e.g. spaces and comma above).

```js
// Parser and formatter using PHP tokens
let P = function(global) {

  let P = {lang: 'en-GB'};

  // Format tokens and functions
  let tokens = {
  
    // DAY
    // day of month, pad to 2 digits
    d: d => pad(d.getDate()),
    // Day name, first 3 letters
    D: d => getDayName(d).substr(0,3),
    // day of month, no padding
    j: d => d.getDate(),
    // Full day name
    l: d => getDayName(d),
    // ISO weekday number (1 = Monday ... 7 = Sunday)
    N: d => d.getDay() || 7,
    // Ordinal suffix for day of the month
    S: d => getOrdinal(d.getDate()),
    // Weekday number (0 = Sunday, 6 = Saturday)
    w: d => d.getDay(),
    // Day of year, 1 Jan is 0
    z: d => {
      let Y = d.getFullYear(),
          M = d.getMonth(),
          D = d.getDate();
      return Math.floor((Date.UTC(Y, M, D) - Date.UTC(Y, 0, 1)) / 8.64e7) ;
    },
    // ISO week number of year
    W: d => getWeekNumber(d)[1],
    // Full month name
    F: d => getMonthName(d),
    // Month number, padded
    m: d => pad(d.getMonth() + 1),
    // 3 letter month name
    M: d => getMonthName(d).substr(0, 3),
    // Month number, no pading
    n: d => d.getMonth() + 1,
    // Days in month
    t: d => new Date(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth() + 1, 0).getDate(),
    // Return 1 if d is a leap year, otherwise 0
    L: d => new Date(d.getFullYear(), 1, 29).getDate() == 29? 1 : 0,
    // ISO week numbering year
    o: d => getWeekNumber(d)[0],
    // 4 digit year
    Y: d => {
      let year = d.getFullYear();
      if (year < 0) {
        year = '-' + ('000' + Math.abs(year)).slice(-4);
      }
      return year;
    },
    // 2 digit year
    y: d => {
      let year = d.getFullYear();
      if (year >= 0) {
        return ('0' + year).slice(-2);
      } else {
        year = Math.abs(year);
        return - + ('0' + year).slice(-2);
      }
    },
    // Lowercase am or pm
    a: d => d.getHours() < 12? 'am' : 'pm',
    // Uppercase AM or PM
    A: d => d.getHours() < 12? 'AM' : 'PM',
    // Swatch internet time
    B: d => (((+d + 3.6e6) % 8.64e7) / 8.64e4).toFixed(0),
    // 12 hour hour no padding
    g: d => (d.getHours() % 12) || 12,
    // 24 hour hour no padding
    G: d => d.getHours(),
    // 12 hour hour padded
    h: d => pad((d.getHours() % 12) || 12),
    // 24 hour hour padded
    H: d => pad(d.getHours()),
    // Minutes padded
    i: d => pad(d.getMinutes()),
    // Seconds padded
    s: d => pad(d.getSeconds()),
    // Microseconds padded - always returns 000000
    u: d => '000000',
    // Milliseconds
    v: d => padd(d.getMilliseconds()),
    // Timezone identifier: UTC, GMT or IANA Tz database identifier - Not supported
    e: d => void 0,
    // If in daylight saving: 1 yes, 0 no
    I: d => d.getTimezoneOffset() == getOffsets(d)[0]? 0 : 1,
    // Difference to GMT in hours, e.g. +0200
    O: d => minsToHours(-d.getTimezoneOffset(), false),
    // Difference to GMT in hours with colon, e.g. +02:00
    P: d => minsToHours(-d.getTimezoneOffset(), true),
    // Timezone abbreviation, e.g. AEST. Dodgy but may work…
    T: d => d.toLocaleString('en',{year:'numeric',timeZoneName:'long'}).replace(/[^A-Z]/g, ''),
    // Timezone offset in seconds, +ve east
    Z: d => d.getTimezoneOffset() * -60,
    
    // ISO 8601 format - UTC
    // c: d => d.getUTCFullYear() + '-' + pad(d.getUTCMonth() + 1) + '-' + pad(d.getUTCDate()) +
    //        'T' + pad(d.getUTCHours()) + ':' + pad(d.getUTCMinutes()) + ':' + pad(d.getUTCSeconds()) +
    //        '+00:00',
    
    // ISO 8601 format - local
    c: d => P.format(d, 'Y-m-d\\TH:i:sP'),
    // RFC 2822 formatted date, local timezone
    r: d => P.format(d, 'D, d M Y H:i:s O'),
    // Seconds since UNIX epoch (same as ECMAScript epoch)
    U: d => d.getTime() / 1000 | 0
  };
  
  // Helpers
  // Return day name for date
  let getDayName = d => d.toLocaleString(P.lang, {weekday:'long'});
  // Return month name for date
  let getMonthName = d => d.toLocaleString(P.lang, {month:'long'});
  // Return [std offest, DST offset]. If no DST, same offset for both
  let getOffsets = d => {
    let y = d.getFullYear();
    let offsets = [0, 2, 5, 9].map(m => new Date(y, m).getTimezoneOffset());
    return [Math.max(...offsets), Math.min(...offsets)];
  }  
  // Return ordinal for positive integer
  let getOrdinal = n => {
    n = n % 100;
    let ords = ['th','st','nd','rd'];
    return (n < 10 || n > 13) ? ords[n%10] || 'th' : 'th';
  };
  // Return ISO week number and year
  let getWeekNumber = d => {
    let e = new Date(Date.UTC(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth(), d.getDate()));
    e.setUTCDate(e.getUTCDate() + 4 - (e.getUTCDay()||7));
    var yearStart = new Date(Date.UTC(e.getUTCFullYear(),0,1));
    var weekNo = Math.ceil(( ( (e - yearStart) / 86400000) + 1)/7);
    return [e.getUTCFullYear(), weekNo];
  };
  // Return true if o is a Date, otherwise false
  let isDate = o => Object.prototype.toString.call(o) == '[object Date]';
  // Convert numeric minutes to +/-HHMM or +/-HH:MM
  let minsToHours = (mins, colon) => {
    let sign = mins < 0? '-' : '+';
    mins = Math.abs(mins);
    let H = pad(mins / 60 | 0);
    let M = pad(mins % 60);
    return sign + H + (colon? ':' : '') + M;
  };
  // Pad single digits with a leading zero
  let pad = n => (n < 10? '0' : '') + n;
  // Pad single digits with two leading zeros, double digits with one leading zero
  let padd = n => (n < 10? '00' : n < 100? '0' : '') + n;
  // To be completed...
  let parse = s => 'not complete';

  P.parse = parse;
  
  // Format date using token string s
  function format(date, s) {
    // Minimal input validation
    if (!isDate(date) || typeof s != 'string') {
      return; // undefined
    }

    return s.split('').reduce((acc, c, i, chars) => {
      // Add quoted characters to output
      if (c == '\\') {
        acc += chars.splice(i+1, 1);
      // If character matches a token, use it
      } else if (c in tokens) {
        acc += tokens[c](date);
      // Otherwise, just add character to output
      } else {
        acc += c;
      }
      return acc;
    }, '');
  }
  P.format = format;
  
  return P;
}(this);


// Examples
console.log('Today is ' + P.format(new Date(), 'l, jS \\o\\f F, Y'));
let startPWars = new Date(-431,3,25);
let endPWars   = new Date(-404,0);
console.log('The Peloponnesian Wars started on ' + 
  P.format(startPWars, 'd F, Y') +
  ' and ended in ' +
  P.format(endPWars, 'Y'));

function showDate() {
  let format = document.getElementById('i0').value;
  document.getElementById('sp0').textContent = P.format(new Date(), format) || 'invalid tokens';
}
```

```html
<input id="i0" placeholder="PHP format, e.g. d-M-Y">
<button onclick="showDate()">Show formatted date</button>
<br>
<span id="sp0"></span>
```

Comment: Thanks, I will investigate, but looks like something that I am looking for.

Comment: Great function, @RobG, thanks! But for "y" (two-digits year notation) it will not work correctly for years >1999 as JS will return three-digits number (say, 119 for 2019 year). Probably, `new String(a.getFullYear()).substr(-2)` would be better.

Comment: @WASD42—indeed, fails for any year outside the 20th century. I've applied your suggested edit but that won't work for negative years. I'll work on it a little more when I have time. :-)

Comment: @RobG Do you mean BC years by "negative"? It should work just fine, depending on what is supposed to be shown, of course, as a two-digit year. Say,
```var d = new Date('1900-01-01'); d.setYear(-710); console.log(('0' + d.getFullYear()).substr(-2));``` will log "10" to the console.

Comment: @WASD42—it now returns a leading `-` for years before 1 (negative, BC, BCE, whatever) for both two and four digit years. What does PHP do? PS not sure of the historical value of the Gregorian calendar extended back that far, maybe for years is OK but days and months is moot.